# Name Error on a class method previously defined and IndexError on an Index that should exist

Tags: python, nameerror, index-error

so, I'm getting a NameError on npc.name(and I imagine it will arise in all subsequent class method-linked variables I'm trying to redefine), also, I have an IndexError arising earlier.

I'll explain in more detail,but first, my code.

This is my full code, beware:

```
# import pickle
import pickle
npcs_pickle_file = 'NPCatt.pk'
npc_count = 200

class NPC:
    def __init__(self, name="", occupation="", weakness="", need="", desire="", enemy="",
                 rumor="", secret="", passion="", redeeming_quality="",damning_quality="", happy="",
                 occ_desire="", occ_complication="", pc_opinion="", accomplishment="", magical_gear="",
                 political_influence="", resource="", intel="", research=""):

        # Attributes
        self.name = name
        self.occupation = occupation
        self.weakness = weakness
        self.need = need
        self.desire = desire
        self.enemy = enemy
        self.rumor = rumor
        self.secret = secret
        self.passion = passion
        self.redeeming_quality = redeeming_quality
        self.damning_quality=damning_quality
        self.happy = happy
        self.occ_desire = occ_desire
        self.occ_complication = occ_complication
        self.pc_opinion = pc_opinion
        self.accomplishment = accomplishment
        self.magical_gear = magical_gear
        self.political_influence = political_influence
        self.resource = resource
        self.intel = intel
        self.research = research


    def __str__(self):
        npc_output = "####NPC SUMMARY####\n"
        for att, val in self.__dict__.items():
            if val:
                npc_output += (f"{att} = {val}\n")
        return npc_output

# open a pickle file
# load your data back to memory when you need it
try:
    with open(npcs_pickle_file, 'rb') as fi:
        npcs = pickle.load(fi)
except FileNotFoundError as fne:
    #file doesnt exist prob first time running so create a dict with the 170 npc id's
    npcs = {id: None for id in range(npc_count)}


#select an NPC to modify / create
npc_id = None
while not npc_id:
    try:
        npc_id = int(input(f"Enter the id number of the NPC you wish to modify: "))
    except ValueError as ve:
        print("You must provide a numerical id")

    if npc_id < 0 or npc_id >= npc_count:
        npc_id = None
        print(f"you must provide a value between 0 and {npc_count}")



if npcs[npc_id]:
    npc = npcs[npc_id]
    print(npc)
    modify = input("This NPC already exists, do you want to continue and change them? (y/n): ")
    if modify.lower() == "y":
        name = input("Enter name of NPC: ") 
        occupation = input("Enter NPC occupation: ")
        weakness= input("Enter Weakness: ")
        need= input("Enter Need: ")
        desire= input("Enter Desire: ")
        enemy= input("Enter Enemy: ")
        rumor= input("Enter Rumor: ")
        secret= input("Enter Secret: ")
        passion= input("Enter Passion: ")
        redeeming_quality=input("Enter Redeeming Quality: ")
        damning_quality=input("Enter Damning Quality: ")
        happy= input("Enter, is this NPC happy?: ")
        occ_desire= input("Enter an Occupational Desire: ")
        occ_complication= input("Enter an Occupational Complication: ")
        pc_opinion= input("Enter this NPC's disposition toward the PCs: ")
        accomplishment= input("Enter an Accomplishment: ")
        magical_gear= input("Enter Magical Gear: ")
        political_influence=input("Enter Political Influence: ")
        resource= input("Enter Resource Level: ")
        intel= input("Enter Intel Tier: ")
        research= input("Enter Research: ")

        npc.name = name
        npc.occupation = occupation
        npc.weakness = weakness
        npc.need = need
        npc.desire= desire
        npc.enemy= enemy
        npc.rumor= rumor
        npc.secret= secret
        npc.passion= passion
        npc.redeeming_quality= redeeming_quality
        npc.damning_quality= damning_quality
        npc.happy= happy
        npc.occ_desire=occ_desire
        npc.occ_complication=occ_complication
        npc.pc_opinion=pc_opinion
        npc.accomplishment=accomplishment
        npc.magical_gear=magical_gear
        npc.political_influence=political_influence
        npc.resource=resource
        npc.intel=intel
        npc.research=research


    else:    

        npcs[npc_id] = NPC(name=npc.name, occupation=npc.occupation,weakness=npc.weakness,need=npc.need,desire=npc.desire,\
                       enemy=npc.enemy,rumor=npc.rumor,secret=npc.secret,passion=npc.passion,redeeming_quality=npc.redeeming_quality,\
                       damning_quality=npc.damning_quality,happy=npc.happy,occ_desire=npc.occ_desire,\
                       occ_complication=npc.occ_complication\
                       ,pc_opinion=npc.pc_opinion,accomplishment=npc.accomplishment,\
                       magical_gear=npc.magical_gear,political_influence=npc.political_influence,resource=npc.resource,\
                       intel=npc.intel,research=npc.research)
else:
    name = input("Enter name of NPC: ") 
    occupation = input("Enter NPC occupation: ")
    weakness= input("Enter Weakness: ")
    need= input("Enter Need: ")
    desire= input("Enter Desire: ")
    enemy= input("Enter Enemy: ")
    rumor= input("Enter Rumor: ")
    secret= input("Enter Secret: ")
    passion= input("Enter Passion: ")
    redeeming_quality=input("Enter Redeeming Quality: ")
    damning_quality=input("Enter Damning Quality: ")
    happy= input("Enter, is this NPC happy?: ")
    occ_desire= input("Enter an Occupational Desire: ")
    occ_complication= input("Enter an Occupational Complication: ")
    pc_opinion= input("Enter this NPC's disposition toward the PCs: ")
    accomplishment= input("Enter an Accomplishment: ")
    magical_gear= input("Enter Magical Gear: ")
    political_influence=input("Enter Political Influence: ")
    resource= input("Enter Resource Level: ")
    intel= input("Enter Intel Tier: ")
    research= input("Enter Research: ")
    npc.name = name
    npc.occupation = occupation
    npc.weakness = weakness
    npc.need = need
    npc.desire= desire
    npc.enemy= enemy
    npc.rumor= rumor
    npc.secret= secret
    npc.passion= passion
    npc.redeeming_quality= redeeming_quality
    npc.damning_quality= damning_quality
    npc.happy= happy
    npc.occ_desire=occ_desire
    npc.occ_complication=occ_complication
    npc.pc_opinion=pc_opinion
    npc.accomplishment=accomplishment
    npc.magical_gear=magical_gear
    npc.political_influence=political_influence
    npc.resource=resource
    npc.intel=intel
    npc.research=research


with open(npcs_pickle_file, 'wb') as fi:
    # dump your data into the file
    pickle.dump(npcs, fi)
```

I'm a noob so the code structure was provided as an answer on my only other question so far on the site. I've expanded it for my purposes.

The thing is, the NPC indexed as [1], has been stored perfectly, shows up as needed, and is modifiable.
But when defining new NPCs, I get first an IndexError for new Indexable NPCs, which I caught with a

```
try: #the code for when the NPC has been previously defined
except IndexError:#the code on the last else block, for new indexes
```

in order to check whether the rest of the code worked,
and a NameError arises on the last else block where I define each attribute as

```
self.att=att
```

now, my best guess is that it has to do with local vs global variable definitions, but I have no idea how to solve either error.

Thank you if you read all the way through, and I'm sorry.
Please help, if you can and want to.

Comment: In your `else` block you have no `npc` defined. I assume you want to create a new NPC, so you have to create one (`npc = NPC()`) before trying to access the attributes.

Comment: BTW, there is a huge duplicate code block. Try to put that in a function.

Comment: Also, you're using a pretty weird pattern here. Specifically the `npcs = {id: None for id in range(npc_count)}` section is going to cause you trouble. You then end up saying you have an NPC at, say, 7, but really you're pointing to a None. So sometimes it'll be an NPC and sometimes a None, which will likely cause you trouble.

Comment: @Matthias  I'll attempt to define `npc=NPC()` on the else block, yeah. I was thinking of using a function for the duplicate code block, but i first wanted to make sure that the code's concept itself worked, since it broke beyond index 1

Comment: @AidanKane , yes I thought it looked weird, but that is how the kind user that structured my code did it, and being a noob, I didn't really get how it was supposed to work either way, I just assumed it to be correct

Comment: Part of your problem is that you already have a saved npcs file, but not in the expected format - it's coming from your previous script version obviously where you pickled a `list` (`NPCatt`). The simplest solution to this is to rename this file (or just delete it if you don't care about the content) so you start with a clean state. If you have valid data in the existing file, you will have to write a migration script to import them in your new format - but only after you have something working and stable enough, else it would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IndexError` issue comes from unpickling a file created by the previous version of your script. If this file contains valuable data, just rename it for the moment, and once you'll get you script working and stable enough, it will be time to write a migration script to get your old data back. Else, well, just ditch it xD

wrt/ the NameError, it's in the last `else` block: you are trying to set attributes on a `npc` variable that is indeed not defined at this point - it's only defined in the `if` block:

```
if npcs[npc_id]:
    npc = npcs[npc_id]
    # way too much code here
else:
    # repeated code here
    # and here's the issue:
    npc.something = something
```

You already noticed that "mashing together pieces of code without understanding them doesn't always work", which is a good start (at least you're aware of it, so there's still hope xD), now here's another enlightenment for you: "trying to understand messy code is hard". That's why good code structure is important. Also, short functions that only (or mostly) depend on their arguments are easier to understand (and test !) than long scripts with lots of conditionals and code blocks that depends on some variable being (or not) defined some 20+ lines away.

I usually don't do this, but it seems that in this case, you may benefit from seeing what a decently structured code looks like. It's far from perfect and could benefit from some improvements (like, when editing an existing npc, letting the user specify which attributes he wants to change instead of asking them to retype everything) but well, that's your job, not mine ;-)

```
import pickle

# coding conventions: pseudo-constants should be ALL_UPPER
NPCS_PICKLE_FILE = 'NPCatt.pk'
NPC_COUNT = 200

# coding convention: class names should be CamelCase
class Npc:
    def __init__(self, name="", occupation="", weakness="", need="", desire="", enemy="",
                 rumor="", secret="", passion="", redeeming_quality="",damning_quality="", happy="",
                 occ_desire="", occ_complication="", pc_opinion="", accomplishment="", magical_gear="",
                 political_influence="", resource="", intel="", research=""):

        # Attributes
        self.name = name
        self.occupation = occupation
        self.weakness = weakness
        self.need = need
        self.desire = desire
        self.enemy = enemy
        self.rumor = rumor
        self.secret = secret
        self.passion = passion
        self.redeeming_quality = redeeming_quality
        self.damning_quality = damning_quality
        self.happy = happy
        self.occ_desire = occ_desire
        self.occ_complication = occ_complication
        self.pc_opinion = pc_opinion
        self.accomplishment = accomplishment
        self.magical_gear = magical_gear
        self.political_influence = political_influence
        self.resource = resource
        self.intel = intel
        self.research = research

    def update(self, **values):
        for key, val in values.items():
            # make sure we're only accepted known attributes
            if not hasattr(self, key):
                raise AttributeError("Npc object has no attribute '{}'".format(key))
            setattr(self, key, val)

    def __str__(self):
        # in Python, string concatenation is better done by
        # building a list and joining it afterward
        npc_output = ["####NPC SUMMARY####"] 
        for att, val in self.__dict__.items():
            if val:
                npc_output.append(f"{att} = {val}")
        npc_output.append("") # so we have a last newline
        return "\n".join(npc_output)


class InvalidDataFile(ValueError):
    pass


def load_npcs_from_file():
    with open(NPCS_PICKLE_FILE, 'rb') as fi:
        try:
            npcs = pickle.load(fi)
        except EOFError as e:
            raise InvalidDataFile(
                "looks like {} is empy - expected a dict, got {}".format(NPCS_PICKLE_FILE, e)
            )

    # make sure we don't have incorrect data from
    # the previous version where what was pickled was a list
    if not isinstance(npcs, dict):
        raise InvalidDataFile(
            "looks like {} is obsolete or corrupted - expected a dict, got {}".format(NPCS_PICKLE_FILE, ncps)
    )

    # make sure we ALWAYS have `NPC_COUNT` npcs whatever
    # (ie: in case the pickle didn't have as many entries as expected)
    missing = NPC_COUNT - len(npcs)
    if missing > 0:
        for id in range(NPC_COUNT):
            ncps.setdefault(id, None)
    return npcs

def init_npcs():
    return {id: None for id in range(NPC_COUNT)}

def load_npcs():
    try:
        return load_npcs_from_file()

    except (FileNotFoundError, InvalidDataFile) as e:
        # so you know what's happening...
        print("got {} when trying to load npcs from file - creating a new dataset".format(e))
        return init_npcs()


def save_npcs(npcs):
    with open(NPCS_PICKLE_FILE, 'wb') as fi:
        # dump your data into the file
        pickle.dump(npcs, fi)    


def get_npc_values():
    # factor out common stuff
    # XXX you definitly want to validate user inputs
    values = {}

    values["name"] = input("Enter name of NPC: ") 
    values["occupation"] =  input("Enter NPC occupation: ")
    values["weakness"] =  input("Enter Weakness: ")
    values["need"] =  input("Enter Need: ")
    values["desire"] =  input("Enter Desire: ")
    values["enemy"] =  input("Enter Enemy: ")
    values["rumor"] =  input("Enter Rumor: ")
    values["secret"] =  input("Enter Secret: ")
    values["passion"] =  input("Enter Passion: ")
    values["redeeming_quality"] = input("Enter Redeeming Quality: ")
    values["damning_quality"] = input("Enter Damning Quality: ")
    values["happy"] =  input("Enter, is this NPC happy?: ")
    values["occ_desire"] =  input("Enter an Occupational Desire: ")
    values["occ_complication"] =  input("Enter an Occupational Complication: ")
    values["pc_opinion"] =  input("Enter this NPC's disposition toward the PCs: ")
    values["accomplishment"] =  input("Enter an Accomplishment: ")
    values["magical_gear"] =  input("Enter Magical Gear: ")
    values["political_influence"] = input("Enter Political Influence: ")
    values["resource"] =  input("Enter Resource Level: ")
    values["intel"] =  input("Enter Intel Tier: ")
    values["research"] =  input("Enter Research: ")

    return values

def update_npc(npc):
    new_values = get_npc_values()
    npc.update(**new_values)

def create_npc():
    values = get_npc_values()
    return Npc(**values)

def get_npc_id():
    #select an NPC to modify / create
    npc_id = None
    while npc_id is None:
        try:
            npc_id = int(input(f"Enter the id number of the NPC you wish to modify: "))
        except ValueError as ve:
            print("You must provide a numerical id")

        if npc_id < 0 or npc_id >= NPC_COUNT:
            npc_id = None
            print(f"you must provide a value between 0 and {NPC_COUNT}")

    return npc_id


def edit_npc(npcs):
    npc_id = get_npc_id()

    # this should be safe now... theoretically at least
    npc = npcs[npc_id]


    if npc is None:
        ok = input("This NPC doesn't exist yet, do you want to create it (y/n): ")
        if ok.strip().lower() == 'y':
            npcs[npc_id] = create_npc()
            # let the caller know something was changed
            return True
    else:
        ok = input("This NPC already exists, do you want to continue and change them? (y/n): ")
        if ok.strip().lower() == "y":
            update_npc(npc)
            # let the caller know something was changed
            return True

    # let the caller know nothing was changed
    return False

def show_npcs(npcs):
    for id, npc in npcs.items():
        print("{} : {}".format(id, npc))
    print("") # add a blank line


def get_next_action():
    while True:
        print("what do you want to do ?")
        print("S - show existing npcs")
        print("E - edit a npc")
        print("Q - quit")

        action = input(">> ").strip().upper()
        if action not in "SEQ":
            print("sorry, I don't undertand '{}'".format(action))
        return action



def main():
    npcs = load_npcs()

    while True:
        nb_valids = len([_ for _ in npcs.values() if _])
        print("we have {} valid npcs".format(nb_valids))

        action = get_next_action()

        if action == "Q":
            break

        elif action == "E":
            if edit_npc(npcs):
                print("saving data")
                save_npcs(npcs)

        elif action == "S":
            show_npcs(npcs)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It definitely helps to have the different steps broken down into small functions, I understand most of your version of the code, which in itself, is an achievement XD. Thanks for "enlightening" me, I might even become a decent coder one day, thanks to you all. I hope one day I can give back! For now though, I'm going to be messing with this new toy and learning from it :P Made my day!

Comment: This Error arises as I try to edit, tho:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\short\brunodesthulliers NPCs.py", line 241, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\short\brunodesthulliers NPCs.py", line 227, in main
    if edit_npc(npcs):
  File "C:\Users\short\brunodesthulliers NPCs.py", line 183, in edit_npc
    update_npc(npc)
  File "C:\Users\short\brunodesthulliers NPCs.py", line 145, in update_npc
    npc.update(**new_values)
  File "C:\Users\short\brunodesthulliers NPCs.py", line 42, in update
    setattr(self, key, value)
NameError: name 'value' is not defined`

Comment: @Icarus there's a typo indeed (well, there was one at least) - but the error message and traceback tell you all you need to know to fix it in less time than it takes to post a comment here ;-)